# Scrape values from json python requests

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup, python-requests, scrape

So I am building a **scraper** for sizes on a site and I am confused how to extract the "EUR" and "pieces" from this json.... I want to **print later all sizes like "EU 41 = Pieces 6"**. probably I need a for loop

Here ist the output of the json : *"{'translations': {'en': {'lang': 'en', 'title': 'Nike Dunk Low Retro Premium', 'subtitle': 'Black / Pure Platinum-Anthracite', 'slug': 'nike-dunk-low-retro-premium', 'description': 'DH7913-001'}}, 'id': 'vpEW0nkBHBhvh4GFDXSb', 'prices': {'EUR': {'currency': 'EUR', 'value': 119}}, 'sizeSets': {'Men': {'name': 'Men', 'sizes': [{'id': '685d200c-c470-11eb-b5ee-a66da43170c1', 'us': '8', 'eur': '41', 'uk': '7', 'cm': '26', 'ean': '194955875308', 'pieces': 6}, {'id': '685d21c4-c470-11eb-9f9f-a66da43170c1', 'us': '8.5', 'eur': '42', 'uk': '7.5', 'cm': '26.5', 'ean': '194955875315', 'pieces': 18}, {'id': '685d232c-c470-11eb-8bda-a66da43170c1', 'us': '9', 'eur': '42.5', 'uk': '8', 'cm': '27', 'ean': '194955875322', 'pieces': 10}, {'id': '685d248a-c470-11eb-bf78-a66da43170c1', 'us': '9.5', 'eur': '43', 'uk': '8.5', 'cm': '27.5', 'ean': '194955875339', 'pieces': 17}, {'id': '685d25de-c470-11eb-8741-a66da43170c1', 'us': '10', 'eur': '44', 'uk': '9', 'cm': '28', 'ean': '194955875346', 'pieces': 15}, {'id': '685d2732-c470-11eb-bfb5-a66da43170c1', 'us': '10.5', 'eur': '44.5', 'uk': '9.5', 'cm': '28.5', 'ean': '194955875353', 'pieces': 5}, {'id': '685d2886-c470-11eb-ac68-a66da43170c1', 'us': '11', 'eur': '45', 'uk': '10', 'cm': '29', 'ean': '194955875360', 'pieces': 1}, {'id': '685d29e4-c470-11eb-8578-a66da43170c1', 'us': '11.5', 'eur': '45.5', 'uk': '10.5', 'cm': '29.5', 'ean': '194955875377', 'pieces': 2}, {'id': '685d2b38-c470-11eb-a729-a66da43170c1', 'us': '12', 'eur': '46', 'uk': '11', 'cm': '30', 'ean': '194955875384', 'pieces': 3}]}, 'Unisex': {'name': 'Unisex', 'sizes': []}, 'Women': {'name': 'Women', 'sizes': []}, 'Kids': {'name': 'Kids', 'sizes': []}}, 'images': ['0/08/083/0837c383a3212d52f2e4455e0d876f47.jpeg', 'c/ca/ca0/ca01c2ca1dfb35013a06723b60c062cc.jpeg', '8/8e/8e9/8e9d04f6d1e8712da6d85c3db98ff989.jpeg', '3/37/376/3769e3f56186e46b91c725d09dff3252.jpeg', 'a/aa/aa5/aa5a8934a05be2badfe9cff5e07f122c.jpeg', '7/7b/7b0/7b088912b94bb0b2e41d527d573d568d.jpeg', 'b/b8/b8b/b8b214b6e1a33d56880e412b7ef8fe01.jpeg', '5/56/562/562809e497cc98b69cf8789e3238e482.jpeg'], 'imagesPortrait': ['a/ab/abc/abc1eac4bcdf74bd899f8e2f7827f30c.jpeg'], 'createdAt': '2021-06-03T13:34:22+00:00', 'publishAt': '2021-06-10T10:00:00+00:00', 'openRegistrationAt': '2021-06-10T10:00:00+00:00', 'closeRegistrationAt': '2021-06-18T23:00:00+00:00', 'finished': True, 'headliner': False, 'code': 'DH7913-001', 'footshopLink': 'https://www.footshop.eu/en/723-limited-edition/orderby-activated_at/orderway-desc', 'soldout': False, 'deleted': False, 'limitedShipping': True, 'delayedExport': False, 'productIdentifier': '115147', 'status': 'Closed',
'resultAt': '2021-06-19T03:00:00+00:00'}"*

```py
from os import error
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from discord_webhook import DiscordWebhook,DiscordEmbed
import time
import json


URL= "https://releases.footshop.com/api/raffles/vpEW0nkBHBhvh4GFDXSb"




headers = {
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36"}

page = requests.get(URL,headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')



site_info= page.json()
print(site_info)
```

Answer (score 1):

For the Json, I would recommend you first put it in a Json viewer/reader you can find online to see how is the data is more clearly and where is the information you want to get.

Here something like that should get you the information you want :

```
for s in site_info['sizeSets']['Men']['sizes']:
    print(s['eur']+' '+ str(s['pieces']))
```